# The panel's icons are messed up

Tags: 14.04, unity, icons

Yesterday I turned off my laptop(normal usage... without any new package installation), and after I turned on my laptop my menu bar's icon are messed like below:
[image]
which gone icons are for bluetooth and keyboard layout(language).

I really don't know why should this happen. because at the time this happened I am 100% sure that I didn't do anything out of normal usage(just playing music and programming) to cause this.

## Question

How can i fix this annoying icons?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth...
I finally fixed the problem, I noticed the problem was with `ubuntu-mono-dark` icon theme. So I decided to reinstall the theme:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mono
```

It is all good now :)